# How to remove ubuntu and make Windows bootable again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, live-usb, boot-repair

I am desperately trying to get Windows to boot again.
Here's what happened.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 a while ago using a USB flash drive onto my hard drive. It never booted when I tried to boot up, it would always go to Windows 8.1 (my normal operating system). Today I was messing with things and decided to make the Ubuntu partition bootable using Ubuntu. It somehow hid the partition from the Disks application. I didn't really think about it until I tried to boot Windows 8.1 back up. Every time I boot it up, it says "BootDevice not found". I went back into Ubuntu using my USB and made it unbootable. But, even after that, it still says "BootDevice not found" when trying to boot with my hard drive.

I am desperate and I'm afraid I messed up my entire computer. If someone could get me an answer quickly I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much.

**EDIT:** Also, I don't have any CD/DVD slot in my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me once. What I did was I booted from the USB that I had used to install Ubuntu. From there, I installed another version of Ubuntu onto the hard drive and then used the grub from this version of Ubuntu to access my other OS (I was using Elementary OS).

Comment: Oh my goodness! It works. *Thanks a million!* I truly thought that I had completely destroyed my computer.